First step analysis - extension to more complicated cases
Let $X$ be a Markov Chain, with values in a countable state space $S$ and transition matrix $P=(p(s,s'))_{s,s'\in S}$. We fix $D\subset S$. Let $c:D\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\psi:D^c\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Let $T:=\inf\{n\geq 0: X_n\in D^c\}$ be a stopping time with respect to the canonical filtration generated by $X$. Define further for every $s\in D$
$$h(s):=\mathbb E_s\Big[\psi(X_T)\mathbf 1_{\{T<\infty\}}+\sum_{m<T}c(X_m)\Big].$$
Then, first step analysis implies that $h$ fulfils the following set of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
h(s)&=\psi(s),&\text{ if $s\in D^c$.}\\
h(s)&=\sum_{s'\in S}p(s,s')h(s')+c(s),&\text{if $s\in D$.}
\end{align*}
$$
The proof of this is just conditioning on $\mathcal F_1$.
If I am considering the Gambler's ruin, and want to compute the average game duration given that one specific player wins, I would do the following: Let $T_0:=\inf\{n\geq 0:X_n=0\}$. We set $D:=\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, $D^c:=\{0,n\}$. Further $c\equiv1$, and $\psi(0)=1$, and $\psi(n)=0$. Then, we get
$$h(s)=\mathbb E_s[\mathbf 1_{\{T_0<\infty\}}+T_0]=\mathbb P_s(T_0<\infty)+\mathbb E_s[T_0].$$
By first step analysis, $h$ fulfils
$$
\begin{align*}
h(s)&=p\,h(s+1)+q\,h(s-1)+1,\\
h(0)&=\psi(0)=1,\\
h(n)&=\psi(n)=0.
\end{align*}
$$
However, this gives the wrong answer of $n\,(n-k)$ in the symmetric case (expected value of game duration if the game can end in 0 or n, but not the average game duration until absorption in 0). The quantity i am looking for should be $\frac{n\,(n-k)\,(n+k)}{3n}$, or something similar.
How do I implement a condition on finiteness? I would like to have a similar formula but with $\mathbb E[T_0\mathbf 1_{\{T_0<\infty\}}]$. Is there a more general version of the above principle?
The question bases on this post: Expected time for biased Gambler's Ruin, conditioned on winning.
